# correct stored procedure syntax for remote server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I was developing SQL stored procedure for my local environment.But for the first time, I want to deploy the database to my free hosting site called 1freehosting. I have the following stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `post_and_fetch_ans`(IN answerbody longtext,IN postid int,IN answerer int)
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO `login`.`answers` (answer_body,userpost_post_id,users_user_id) VALUES (answerbody,postid,answerer) ;
       SELECT * FROM `login`.`answers` WHERE userpost_post_id = postid  ORDER BY answer_date DESC LIMIT 1;
    END
```

My problem is in the `DEFINER` section.My `local username is root` and so it is logical that i had the statement `'root'@'localhost'`. But my question is what will be the definer section for remote server.I am feeling confused .Informatin of my mysql database are the following :

> my database information is :
>
> mysql username: u377815502_zami
>
> mysql database: u377815502_login
>
> mysql hostname: mysql.1freehosting.com
>
> IP Address:   31.170.166.81
>
> Server IP:    31.170.166.5

Comment: DEFINER is optional. Why not try just leaving it out. Then the definer will be the current user.

Comment: i should directly go for "CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name" ??

Comment: Worth a try, I reckon

Comment: one last sillly question ...i have two stored procedure..can i write both of them in the same sql editor or do have to go one at time ?

Comment: Depends on how the editor code is executed. But the answer should be that it's fine to write them both in one script.

Comment: yes to what ? one at a time or both at a time :(

Comment: `DELIMITER` is an internal command of the official command-line client, you cannot use it from PHP. And whether you can run multiple statements at once, that depends on what database library you are using (I don't think you mentioned it).